# Changing image source dynamically for carousel

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am starting off learning React and building a simple picture carousel. I have 3 images I am pulling from Github in a `const` array. The requirement would be to have a forward and back button to cycle through the images.
Upon app start, the 1st image shows up correctly. The button increments a counter correctly (*I have console logs confirming that*).
But the `<img>` does not refresh/reload loading the next image from the array based on the revised counter variable.

At the moment I only have the forward  button functionality implemented.

```js
const photoList = [
  "https://avatars0.githubusercontent.com/u/810438?v=4",
  "https://avatars2.githubusercontent.com/u/6820?v=4",
  "https://avatars2.githubusercontent.com/u/63648?v=4"
];

//Component for the Forward button

function ForwardButton(props) {
  console.log("Forward Button clicked");
  const handleClick = () => props.OnClick(props.increment);
  return <button onClick={handleClick}> --> </button>;
}

//Component for the Back button

function BackButton() {
  return <button className="BackButton"> {"<--"} </button>;
}

//Main component with other components nested

function App() {
  const state = {
    profiles: photoList
  };

  let count = 0;

  const [counter, setCounter] = useState(0);
  const IncrementCounter = incrementValue => {
    setCounter((count = counter + incrementValue));
    console.log(count);
  };
  return (
    <div className="App">
      <header> Picture Carousal</header>
      <img className="Image" src={state.profiles[count]} />
      <BackButton />
      <ForwardButton OnClick={IncrementCounter} increment={1} />
    </div>
  );
}

ReactDOM.render(<App />, mountNode);
```

I would like to use this very simple implementation and try to figure out how to make `<img>` refresh with new image. Hopefully this is an easy fix.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `count` being defined inside the `App` component gets reset on each re-render.

You will have to either define it outside the component (*but that could create some problems if you want two `App` components at the same time*).

Or you could use the `counter` directly, which is the whole point of using `state`.
(*also use modulo with the length of your array to limit the `counter` to only values matching the images*)

```
const IncrementCounter = incrementValue => {
  setCounter((counter + incrementValue) % photoList.length);
};
```

Demo at https://codesandbox.io/s/nostalgic-browser-qfudx

Comment: Perfect.Thank you. Your explanation makes total sense.